# Android app crash in 512mb ram mobile

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

Hi I created one android application and I uploaded that in a play store, in that app I used navigation drawer to navigate from one activity to another.

My app is working fine in maximum no of mobiles which has 1 GB RAM and the latest OS like KitKat or Lollipop, but in 512 MB RAM mobile and in the Ice_Cream_Sandwich version the app is closing after the start up, saying "Unfortunately the app has stopped". This problem is arising in only few mobiles (I am saying this based upon the user comments in play store).

And my minimum and maximum SDK version is

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

And I didn't add the appcompat v7 as the library, If I add this all my Java class files are showing error.

Now what I need is, I need to know why the crash is happening and how to fix this.

I already made a search in SO but I couldn't able to find the proper solution which I need.

And the crash report I got in play store is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

in android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable.isStateful


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.imaginet.everwinmatriculation/com.imaginet.everwinmatriculation.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable.isStateful(InsetDrawable.java:208)
at android.widget.ImageView.updateDrawable(ImageView.java:697)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:410)
at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.setActionBarUpIndicator
(ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java:62)at  

android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplHC
.setActionBarUpIndicator(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:134)
at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.setActionBarUpIndicator
(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:400)
at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:258)
at com.imaginet.everwinmatriculation.MainActivity.onPostCreate(MainActivity.java:291)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
... 11 more
```

And my MainActivity is...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //From this to - For Internet Connectivity Checking
    ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You Have Active Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("You Don't Have Active Internet Connection, Click Ok To Exit")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //do things
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    //Upto this - For Internet Connectivity Checking
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // About Us
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Principal Speech
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Circulars
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1),   

false, "22"));
    // Internal Events
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    //External Events
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    // Academic Calendar
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    // Admissions
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
    // Competition
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
    // Class Work
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1)));
    // Home Work
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1)));
    // Training & Test
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[11], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(11, -1)));
    // Examination
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[12], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(12, -1)));

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }

    //Following one line is added for onBackPressed Method
    mDrawerLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PrincipalSpeechFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CircularsFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new EventsFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new ExternalEventsFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new AC_CalenderFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new AdmissionsFragment();
        break;
    case 8:
        fragment = new CompetitionFragment();
        break;
    case 9:
        fragment = new ClassWorkFragment();
        break;
    case 10:
        fragment = new HomeWorkFragment();
        break;
    case 11:
        fragment = new TrainingTestFragment();
        break;
    case 12:
        fragment = new ExaminationFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls

    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onBackPressed();

    //Upcmoning line is for confirm exiting
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
    .show();
}
}
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: I need to know why the crash is happening and how to fix this.

Comment: Post bug traces from the Dev Console.

Comment: Hey Bro,This is not your RAM issue.. pls post your bug traces so that we can help you..

Comment: As you are getting a NPE something might have not be initialized correctly. If you could show us relevant parts of your code that initialize your drawer would help.

Comment: protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Sync the toggle state after     onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
  mDrawerToggle.syncState();
 }            In this //mDrawerToggle.syncState(); this is line 291 in main activity @kaushik

Comment: @kaushik how to set that value as null. My problem is. The app is working fine in new mobiles but not in the old devices like samsung s2 and duos and micromax etc...

Comment: Will it create any other problem if I delete that ???

Comment: Could you add the code where you initialise the ActionBarToggle? Looks to me like the problem is that the Drawer icon is null.

Comment: @Qw4z1 Bro, I added my MainActivity Code.

Comment: Two things come to mind here. First; you don't call `super.onDrawerClosed()` or `super.onDrawerOpened` in your actionbar toggle. Don't know if this could cause any issue though. Second; R.drawable.ic_drawer is the drawer icon. Have you verified that this is present in your resources for all versions of Android, ie all res/values versions?

Comment: @kaushik actually I removed that method now its working fine... But I need to test with few more devices. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Why the `if (mDrawerLayout != null) {` statement btw?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the solution for your problem is this:

Just add this line to the application in your manifest file:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

So your Manifest file should application should look like this:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Solves the wrong problem. He get's a NullPointerException, not a OutOfMemoryError.